# Sending IOCTL from IRQL=DISPATCH_LEVEL (KbFilter/KMDF)

Tags: c++, c, driver, kmdf, wdf

I am using the KbFilter example in the WDK, trying to send an IOCTL in a function that is called by KbFilter_ServiceCallback and therefore is executed at DISPATCH_LEVEL. The function just has to send an IOCTL and return, am not waiting for an output buffer to be filled so it can be asynchronous, fire and forget.

I am currently using the WDF functions **WdfIoTargetFormatRequestForIoctl** and **WdfRequestSend** to try and send at DISPATCH_LEVEL and getting nothing. The call to WdfRequestSend is succeeding but the IOCTL doesn't appear to be received.

Using either of **WdfIoTargetSendIoctlSynchronously** or the WDM pattern **IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest() and IoCallDriver()** requires PASSIVE_LEVEL and the only way I know to call these at PASSIVE_LEVEL is to create a separate thread that runs at PASSIVE_LEVEL and pass it instructions via a buffer or a queue, synchronized with a spinlock and semaphore.

Can someone tell me if there is an easier way to pass IOCTLs to the drivers below my filter, or is the thread/queue approach the normal pattern when you need to do things at a higher IRQL? Under what circumstances can I use **[KeRaiseIrql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms801898.aspx)** and is this what I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use IoAllocateIrp and IoCallDriver. They can be run at IRQL <= DISPATCH_LEVEL.

You cannot lower your IRQL (unless it is you who raised it). KeRaiseIrql is used only to raise IRQL. A call to KeRaiseIrql is valid if the caller specifies NewIrql >= CurrentIrql.

Be careful: Is your IOCTL expected at DISPATCH_LEVEL?

Here is a code snippet:

```
PIRP Irp = IoAllocateIrp(DeviceObject->StackSize, FALSE);

Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread  = PsGetCurrentThread(); 
Irp->RequestorMode        = KernelMode; 
Irp->IoStatus.Status      = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED; 
Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0; 

PIO_STACK_LOCATION stack  = IoGetNextIrpStackLocation(Irp); 
stack->MajorFunction      = IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL; 
stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I create the IOCTL request at dispatch level? IoAllocateIrp and IoCallDriver are both ok at dispatch level, but IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest requires passive level.

Comment: actually http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms801530.aspx says it needs at least APC level, whereas http://www.osronline.com/DDKx/kmarch/k104_8ble.htm says it needs to be at passive level.. strange

Comment: Thanks for the code, I am not really familiar with the WDM way, I will give it a try

Comment: IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest really does need to be invoked at PASSIVE_LEVEL.  It marks various parts of the IRP based on your current thread, and the side effects of that may not be what you're looking for at raised IRQL.